# How to deduce the analyticity of a function, $f(z) = \sin (2z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Deduce the analyticity of the function $ f(z) = \sin (2z) $.

Comment: What is your definition of the sine function?

Comment: f(z) = sin (2z) where z = x + iy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then$$\sin\bigl(2(x+yi)\bigr)=\overbrace{\sin(2x)\cosh(2y)}^{=u(x,y)}+\overbrace{\cos(2x)\sinh(2y)}^{=v(x,y)}i.$$It is easy to check that both partial derivatives of both functions $u$ and $v$ are continuous everywhere.

Comment: This was the approach I used in solving the problem. But I was told that the Cauchy-Riemann Equations is a necessity for analyticity not a sufficiency. Because of this, I feel I haven't completely solved the question accurately.

Comment: But every point being a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations **plus** the partial derivatives being continuous **is** enough for analiticity.

Comment: Thanks! I now get the whole concept.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using $\sin2z=\dfrac{1}{2i}\left(e^{2iz}-e^{-2iz}\right)$ where $e^z$ is entire.

Answer (score 0):

If Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied at every point of an open set then the function is analytic in that set. [But if Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied at a particular point you cannot say that the function is analytic at that point].

Comment: I am a bit aware of this. The problem I have is trying to show or rather prove that the partial derivatives of sin (2z) are continuous in a region R so that this sufficiently implies that sin (2z) is an analytic function.

Comment: @NzewiErnestKenechukwu That is unnecessary. Once C-R equtions are verified at all points you can conclude that partial derivatives of all orders exist and they are alll continuous.

Comment: @NzewiErnestKenechukwu Do you know how to write the function in terms of $\sin , \cos, \sinh $ and $\cosh $? There should be no difficulty in proving that the partial derivatives are continuous everywhere. If you show some effort in this direction we can help you.

Comment: Thanks! It's just that as a student, I was being told that analyticity implies differentiability but the converse isn't true. Due to this, I see the Cauchy-Riemann Equations as being a necessity and not a condition for sufficiency.

Comment: I know how to write the function f(z) in terms of sin, cos, sinh & cosh.

Comment: @NzewiErnestKenechukwu you know that these four functions are infinitely differentiable, right?

Comment: Yeah! I know that they are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @NzewiErnestKenechukwu Then I have no idea why you have posted this question.

Comment: I posted the question based on the fact that I wanted to be really sure on what's the difference between analyticity and differentiability. My apologies! Is there a way my question can be placed as an on-topic question in the site. I am new here. I haven't come to the full comprehension of what the mathstack site is all about.

Answer (score 0):

For all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ $$\sin(2z)=(2z)-\frac{(2z)^3}{3!}+\frac{(2z)^5}{5!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}$$
and because radius of convergence of this series is infinite $f$ is analytic on the whole complex plane.

Or if you already know that $\sin z$ is analytic, then because $z\mapsto2z$ is also analytic $f$ is also analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ as a composition of analytic functions.